# Replace Null characters with space from java using power shell command

Tags: powershell, shell, replace, stringtokenizer

I am trying to replace null characters from a text file with space by running powershell command from java program. Below is my code snippet.

Runtime.getRuntime().exec(windowsCommand) method internally uses StringTokenizer which is treating space as token separator. Due to which  {$_.Replace("`0", " ")} are being treated as two tokens.

Any pointers to resolve this or any other ways we can replace null characters from 1 GB file without reading the file. I have to replace null characters before reading it.

```
String windowsCommand = String.format(
                "powershell Get-Content -Path %s -TotalCount 20 | Foreach-Object {$_.Replace(\"`0\", \" \")} | Set-Content -Path %s",
                fitFilePath, fitFilePathUpdated);
        
        String shellCommand = String.format("sh -c tr '\\000' ' ' < \"%s\" > \"%s\"",fitFilePath, fitFilePathUpdated);
        
    Process process = null;
    if (isWindows) {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(windowsCommand);
    } else {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCommand);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just doing the replace operation in java itself? That's sort of the entire point of languages like java and C# - not having to implement the same functionality for multiple platforms :)

Comment: If I read the file before replacing the null characters, java discards all the characters after first null character as null character. while (line = reader.readLine() ! = null)

Comment: Use  `[char]32` instead of string literal `" "` for a space in PowerShell…